# JSGantt Gantt Chart - How to use date variable instead of text

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to Javascript, and have been using JSGantt.js for a Gantt chart on my website.  The only code needed on the html page reads like this:

```
<div style="position:relative" class="gantt" id="GanttChartDIV"></div>
<script>
    // here's all the html code neccessary to display the chart object
    // Future idea would be to allow XML file name to be passed in and chart tasks built from file.

    var g = new JSGantt.GanttChart('g',document.getElementById('GanttChartDIV'), 'quarter');

    g.setShowRes(0); // Show/Hide Responsible (0/1)
    g.setShowDur(0); // Show/Hide Duration (0/1)
    g.setShowComp(0); // Show/Hide % Complete(0/1)
    g.setCaptionType('None');  // Set to Show Caption (None,Caption,Resource,Duration,Complete)
    g.setShowStartDate(0); // Show/Hide Start Date(0/1)
    g.setShowEndDate(0); // Show/Hide End Date(0/1)

    //var gr = new Graphics();

    if( g ) {
        // Parameters (pID, pName, pStart, pEnd,  pColor, pLink, pMile, pRes, pComp, pGroup, pParent, pOpen, pDepend, pCaption)
        // You can also use the XML file parser JSGantt.parseXML('project.xml',g)

        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(1, 'Title',     '', '',  '52A3CC', 'http://www.google.com', 0, 'Team Leader Name', 100, 1, 0, 1));

        g.Draw();   
        g.DrawDependencies();
    }
    else {
        alert("not defined");
    }
</script>
```

In the g.AddTaskItem function, it is expecting a date that is typed into the page.  I would like to use an existing date variable in it's place.

How can I accomplish this?  Thanks for your help!  If you want to see the .js file that is pulling in this information, here it is:

[JS Gantt Download](https://code.google.com/p/jsgantt/downloads/list)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it wants a nice ISO standard date string you could do this:

```
function getDate (days) {
     if (typeof days === "undefined") {
       var days = 0;
     }
     var date = new Date();
     return new Date(date.valueOf() + days*86400000).toISOString().substring(0,10);
}
<snip>
 g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(1, 'Title', getDate(-30), getDate(),  '52A3CC', 'http://www.google.com', 0, 'Team Leader Name', 100, 1, 0, 1));
<snip>
```

`getDate([optional number])` will return today's dateadjusted by how ever many days you give it - or if no argument given will return today instead. You could theoretically do any function there. If that isn't the right date format you could instead of `toISOString().substring(0,10)` use `toDateString()` or one of the other [date functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). If you wanted you could of course adjust the function to even ask the user for a date at runtime.